Combining multiple files with Snakemake: MissingInputException
I'm writing a Snakemake pipeline to run some simulations. The key points are that:
(1) I run simulations across a space of values of parameters A, B & C and in n replicates,
(2) I plot the results averaged across the replicates for each parameter combination,
(3) I want to combine the plots so that, for each combination of B & C, I produce a plot with panels for different values of A.
I'm getting a MissingInputException error associated with step 3.
A minimal version of my Snakefile looks as follows:
A_lst = [0.0, 0.1, 0.01]
B_lst = [0.0, 0.1, 0.01]
C_lst = [0.0, 0.1, 0.01]

seeds = [2,22,42]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("sims/A~{A}/B~{B}/C~{C}/{seed}.out", A=A_lst, B=B_lst, C=C_lst, seed=seeds),
        expand("sims/A~{A}/B~{B}/C~{C}/plot.png", A=A_lst, B=B_lst, C=C_lst),
        expand("plots/combined_B{B}_C{C}.png", B=B_lst, C=C_lst)

rule simulate:
    output:
        "sims/A~{A}/B~{B}/C~{C}/{seed}.out"
    shell:
        "simulator {wildcards.A} {wildcards.B} {wildcards.C} {wildcards.rep}"

rule plot:
    input:
        expand("sims/A~{{A}}/B~{{B}}/C~{{C}}/{seed}.out", seed=seeds)
    output:
        "sims/A~{A}/B~{B}/C~{C}/plot.png"
    shell:
        "scripts/plot.py"


rule combine_plots:
    input:
        expand("output/A~{A}/B~{{B}}/C~{{C}}/plot.png",
        A=A_lst)
    output:
        "plots/combined_B{B}_C{C}.png"
    script:
        "scripts/combine_plots.py"

This gives the following error:
# executing snakemake -n --cores 1 --conda-frontend conda --use-conda
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in rule all in file /data/username/project/Snakefile, line 67:
Missing input files for rule all:
    affected files:
        plots/combined_B0.0_C0.0.png

This surprises me. I thought that the logic would be here as follows:
(1) ask for all possible parameter combination of plots/combined_B{B}_C{C}.png
(2) expand on A while matching the values of B & C from the output
...
The previous two rules work. However, everything to generate plots/combined_B0.0_C0.0.png also seems to be there? I would appreciate some explanation and a suggestion of how to fix it!
Thanks in advance!

there is no python code. so why the python tag ?

I'm unsure why in rule plot you have shell: and then on the next line "scripts/plot.py"? Why not script: in place of shell:, like here? ... .....  Maybe someone else can see the answer without more code shared? Is there anyway you can supply a minimal, reproducible example? Specifically change the line simulator ... to at least make files with the output names expected and similar with "scripts/plot.py". You can comment out those lines. You can make the content empty, we just need dummy files that exactly like you are seeing.

Related to use of shell: in rule plot to run a Python script, you may wish to also see here and links therein.

I copied and ran your Snakefile code (in snakemake 8.11.3) and I get a different error:
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in rule combine_plots in file /home/tbooth2/workspace/snakemake_scratch/stack_overflow/Snakefile, line 28:
Missing input files for rule combine_plots:
    output: plots/combined_B0.0_C0.0.png
    wildcards: B=0.0, C=0.0
    affected files:
        output/A~0.1/B~0.0/C~0.0/plot.png
        output/A~0.0/B~0.0/C~0.0/plot.png
        output/A~0.01/B~0.0/C~0.0/plot.png

This error makes sense since no rules make any files within output/. If I change the input for rule combine_plots to look for files in sims/ then I get:
RuleException in rule simulate in file /home/tbooth2/workspace/snakemake_scratch/stack_overflow/Snakefile, line 13:
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'rep', when formatting the following:
simulator {wildcards.A} {wildcards.B} {wildcards.C} {wildcards.rep}

If I replace {wildcards.rep} with {wildcards.seed} in that shell command then your DAG builds fine:
Job stats:
job              count
-------------  -------
all                  1
combine_plots        9
plot                27
simulate            81
total              118

Obviously I can't test beyond the dry-run, but it looks good to me.
If you have the exact same rules in your own file and are still getting the MissingInputException in rule all error then perhaps you have some wildcard_contraints set elsewhere in the full version of the workflow?
